# Netbox secrets with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to access secrets in Netbox like in this example

https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/working-with-secrets/

but using Powershell but I seem to have hit a brick wall.

Here is my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$Hdrs = @{}
$Hdrs.Add("Authorization","Token fafcaea339cf926c0d79tokenf916aeec2d18bdd")
$Hdrs.Add("Accept","application/json; indent=4")




$body = Get-Content 'c:\key\private.txt'
$body = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($body) 



Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -Uri "http://netbox.et/api/secrets/get-session-key/" -Headers $Hdrs -body $body
```

I just get the error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Private key was not provided.
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is with how I am forming the request, however, I don't know enough about curl to know what '--data' do and how that would look in Powershell. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: To me it is unclear what is the content of your private.txt file. According to the Netbox example page, it should be in the form of `"private_key=$PRIVATE_KEY"`. Also Get-Content without the `-Raw` switch returns a collection of objects, each of which represents a line of content. In your case a single string is needed.

Comment: the private file contains a private key which is generated by Netbox itself, I would say its PGP or something similar. I have added the -raw switch and I get exactly the same error.

Comment: Ok, in that case i think this is JUST the key. You need to send it through the Body with the `"private_key="` prefix like this: `$body = "private_key=" + $body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there were multiple issues. The first that I need to pass the private key as an object with two clear fields like I am the header and the other was I had URL encoded it by defining it in the header and then used a function to URL encode it again, which in turn made the private key invalid.

This is the solution

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$Hdrs = @{}
$body = @{}

$Hdrs.Add("Authorization","Token fafcaea339cf926c0d7977e3ff916aeec2d18bdd")
$Hdrs.Add("Accept","application/json; indent=4")
$Hdrs.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")


$Pkey = Get-Content -raw 'c:\key\private.txt' 

$body.add("private_key",$PKey)


Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -Uri "http://netbox.net/api/secrets/get-session-key/" -Headers $Hdrs -Body $body
```